# twitter share url forgeting the tweet content after login

Tags: api, twitter

I'm trying to add a "share via twitter" link to our website. I'm aware of the standard http://twitter.com/home?status=TWEET method, and it works good enough for my purposes when the user is logged in to twitter already.

If, however, the user is not logged in, twitter displays the login form first (which is only reasonable). After the login, the home screen is displayed without the tweet content.

Am I missing something obvious, or is this a know flaw in this method? If so, what is the easiest way (apart from using services like TweetMeme, which I noticed asks for login in advance) to make the share button work as expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the user is not signed in when accessing http://twitter.com/home?status=TWEET it seems that the status is indeed forgotten. This would be a Twitter website issue and not something you're doing wrong.

**Update:** Use this URL instead: http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=TWEET

TweetMeme, on the other hand, uses its own Twitter "application" via the OAuth authentication, requiring users to log in before retweeting using TweetMeme, and is smart enough to include the tweet message in the OAuth callback URL so that it's not forgotten.

So really, you can:

- Use TweetMeme, where the user would have to log in, but at least have the tweet be remembered once that's done;
- Create your own Twitter application that uses the same tweeting functionality as TweetMeme; or
- Use Twitter.com's less-than-desirable status updater and hope the user is logged in, or hope that they're smart enough to click the back button a couple times and click on your link again if needed.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the following url and parameters

http://twitter.com/share?text=YOUR-TEXT&url=YOUR-URL

Then it works.